# How do I get the path/address of a folder within the program solution? (C#)

Tags: c#, path, directory, subdirectory

I'm trying to get the path for a folder called "Template", which I've created in my project solution. My program is called CalculationScheduler.

I have tried:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

but this gives me the following path:

C:\Users\username\source\repos\AppName\AppName\bin\Debug\

what I want is:

C:\Users\username\source\repos\AppName\AppName\Template

I've also tried:

```
Path.Combine(baseDirectory, @"..\..\Template");
```

I thought that by going back two folders using ..\ ..\ it would work, but it doesn't appear to be.
Bare in mind that this program must also work if installed on another computer.

Comment: You should not have references to files inside your Solution/Project. This path has nothing to do with your Excutable and its resource. When you deploy, that path will not exist. You could instead, in Solution Explorer, select all the Files inside that Folder and set a `Build Action -> Content` and `Copy to Output Directory -> Copy if newer`. When you build you Project/Solution, the files will be copied to the Debug or Release Folders when necessary. This way, you will find them even when you deploy your application, inside `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory\Template`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'll give that a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like below probably

```
Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).FullName).FullName).FullName, "Template")
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would probably to use a [Post Build Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/pre-build-event-post-build-event-command-line-dialog-box?view=vs-2017) in visual studio, a simple statemet like the one below should allow you to copy your ofolder to the output directory

```
XCOPY "$(SolutionDir)\Template" "$(TargetDir)\Template\" /S /Y
```